# Fix Angular 6 issue with unused type and property not existing

Tags: angular, typescript

I've followed this [**video tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4JUm0Bq9AM) and have these errors appearing in my CLI:

1. ERROR in sidebar.component.ts(12,5): error TS7028: Unused label.
2. sidebar.component.ts(14,56): error TS2339: Property 'currentUrl' does not exist on type 'SidebarComponent'.

The code that the errors refer to is:

```
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    currentUrl: String;

    router.events.subscribe((_: NavigationEnd) => this.currentUrl = _.url)
  }
```

In the tutorial between 48:14 and 49:18 the presenter doesn't get any errors with this code whereas my Visual Studio Code underlines both instances `currentURL`. I can't figure out why, nor how to fix?

The only difference between our code I can see is that I used uppercase 'String' instead of 'string' as that in itself produced a separate error.

Can anyone help explain please?

Comment: Duh.. Both answers below are correct. I mistakenly initialized currentURL inside the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize the `currentUrl` outside of the constructor

```
currentUrl: String;
constructor(private router: Router) {

  router.events.subscribe((_: NavigationEnd) => this.currentUrl = _.url)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the correct code

```
export class SidebarComponent {
  currentUrl: String;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((_: NavigationEnd) => this.currentUrl = _.url)
  }
}
```

And I can't see the video but if what you say is true, be glad, your linter is better configured than his !